# requesting a value from a dictionary with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to make a serial generator in python, and when I generate a number, it is assigned to a variable. Now the serial has numbers AND letters. I’m using variables to store each character and at the end I will combine them into one serial. So, far I get numbers for everything, so I set a higher range for the letter spots. I want to call the number from a dictionary using the variable I already have with the number attributed to it.

I’ve already tried printing just the dictionary variable with the variable and it raises an error.

I use the code below:

```
# ironkeys serial gen prototype 1.0 - python 3.7 | 6 character (alternate 
# characters)
import random

v1 = 0
v2 = 0
v3 = 0
v4 = 0
v5 = 0
v6 = 0

d = {10: "A",11: "B",12: "C",13: "D",14: "E",15: "F",16: "G",17: "H",18: 
"I",19: "J",20: "K",21: "L",22: "M",22: "N",23: "O",24: "P",24: "Q",25: 
"R",26: "S",27: "T",28: "U",29: "V",30: "W",31: "X",32: "Y",32: "Z"}

def gen():
    v1 = random.randint(0,9)
    v2 = random.randint(10,33)
    v3 = random.randint(0,9)
    v4 = random.randint(10,33)
    v5 = random.randint(0,9)
    v6 = random.randint(10,33)

def letterAssignAndPrint(v2, v4, v6):
    checkVar1 = d[v2]
    checkVar2 = d[v4]
    checkVar3 = d[v6]
    print(v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)
```

The following error happens when I try to run the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-d45f5b5c2e55> in <module>
----> 1 print(d[v2])

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please put more effort into editing your question, respect the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should mostly work. I don't know why you get Key Error:0. You should occasionally get Key Error: 33 because `random.randint(10,33)` will sometimes make 33, which does not exist in your dictionary. This should work.

```
# ironkeys serial gen prototype 1.0 - python 3.7 | 6 character (alternate characters)
import random

v1 = 0
v2 = 0
v3 = 0
v4 = 0
v5 = 0
v6 = 0

d = {10: "A",11: "B",12: "C",13: "D",14: "E",15: "F",16: "G",17: "H",18: 
"I",19: "J",20: "K",21: "L",22: "M",22: "N",23: "O",24: "P",24: "Q",25: 
"R",26: "S",27: "T",28: "U",29: "V",30: "W",31: "X",32: "Y",32: "Z"}

#def gen():
v1 = random.randint(0,9)
v2 = random.randint(10,32)
v3 = random.randint(0,9)
v4 = random.randint(10,32)
v5 = random.randint(0,9)
v6 = random.randint(10,32)

#def letterAssignAndPrint(v2, v4, v6):
checkVar1 = d[v2]
checkVar2 = d[v4]
checkVar3 = d[v6]

sn = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)
print(v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)


print(sn)
```

which gives

```
8 R 8 W 9 C
8R8W9C
```

The [format function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20format#str.format) replaces all braces ({}) in the template string with provided values. It's a handy way to make a formatted string that contains letters and numbers.

You could also use the [Python % operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). Every %d is replaced by an integer and every %s is replaced by a string.

```
sn = '%d%s%d%s%d%s' % (v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)
```

I didn't see the point of having separate functions `gen` and `letterAssignAndPrint`. If you think you eventually want to have a function, then you have to be careful with variable scope. One way to do this is to return a tuple or a list from your functions:

```
# ironkeys serial gen prototype 1.0 - python 3.7 | 6 character (alternate characters)
import random

v1 = 0
v2 = 0
v3 = 0
v4 = 0
v5 = 0
v6 = 0

d = {10: "A",11: "B",12: "C",13: "D",14: "E",15: "F",16: "G",17: "H",18: 
"I",19: "J",20: "K",21: "L",22: "M",22: "N",23: "O",24: "P",24: "Q",25: 
"R",26: "S",27: "T",28: "U",29: "V",30: "W",31: "X",32: "Y",32: "Z"}

def gen():
    v1 = random.randint(0,9)
    v2 = random.randint(10,32)
    v3 = random.randint(0,9)
    v4 = random.randint(10,32)
    v5 = random.randint(0,9)
    v6 = random.randint(10,32)
    return (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)

def letterAssignAndPrint(v2, v4, v6):
    checkVar1 = d[v2]
    checkVar2 = d[v4]
    checkVar3 = d[v6]
    return (checkVar1, checkVar2, checkVar3)

v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 = gen()
checkVar1, checkVar2, checkVar3 = letterAssignAndPrint(v2, v4, v6)


print(v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)

sn = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(v1, checkVar1, v3, checkVar2, v5, checkVar3)
print(sn)
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just something like this:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits

serial = "".join((choice(digits) + choice(ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(3)))
print(serial)
```

`string.digits = "0123456789"` (see [string constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants)); and [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) selects one of those. the rest is just assembling 3 times a number followed by a letter.

---

in your example `v2` seems to be `0` and there is no key for that in your dictionary `d`.

Comment: i could do that but i also want to be able to customize the order if need be and since i'm a COMPLETE beginner i barely even know that stuff

Comment: customize the order of what exactly? this should get you started with any variant of letter-digits combination you want.

Answer (score 2):

The variables v1 to v6 in def gen() are local to the function gen() and do not update the variables v1 to v6 in the main program.